# Java methods to do zero-copy read on Arrow file?

Tags: java, apache-arrow

Is there a way to do zero-copy/mmap read on Arrow file in Java?
I was reading the doc and it seems such method exists in Python or C++ implementation
(eg: https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/memory.html)

But doesn't seem to have any Java method method to do the same
(eg: https://arrow.apache.org/docs/java/ipc.html)

I could do a mmap on a Arrow file, then wrap it in a seekableChannel and pass it to ArrowFileReader. However, I looked at the source code and found out that the ArrowReader itself is making copies.

Comment: not expert, but you can have a look at `java.nio.channels.FileChannel.transferTo` and `sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl`